# A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: php, error

I am receiving `'A PHP Error was encountered'` error messages when signing into expression engine. Nexcess support sent me the following information. What do I do to get this corrected? I am a novice user and do not know what version I am using. Can you tell me how I find out what version I have as well?

FROM NEXCESS SUPPORT:

> Thank you for reaching out regarding this. It
>   seems that the same scripting error is being thrown into your PHP
>   error log:
>
> ```
> [14-Aug-2017 13:20:28 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function generate_json() on a non-object in  /chroot/home/kansasko/kansas-kofc.org/html/kskofc/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php on line 374
> [14-Aug-2017 21:50:50 America/Detroit] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function generate_json() on a non-object in /chroot/home/kansasko/kansas-kofc.org/html/kskofc/expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php on line 374
> ```
>
> I was able to find an issue on the [ExpressionEngine bug
>   tracker](https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/15445/redirect_function_throws_error_when_calling_generate_json)
>   regarding this error indicating that the Javascript library may not
>   always be loaded on this line.
>
> However, we would not be able to confirm that this is the issue or
>   apply the above patch. I would suggest that you forward these errors
>   to your developers so they can properly debug the scripting issue and
>   implement a fix.
>
> The server is a shared environment so we can't reboot it. I'm not
>   seeing any hanging processes. You may need to reach out to the
>   Expression Engine support since you don't have a developer on staff.
>   This might be a cache issue in the application. Can you clear the
>   cache from the admin panel to see if that clears this?

Comment: In your post you have revealed the address of your server as well as the address of your EE control panel.  This is not a best practice for security.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can clear the cache easily.

For EE3 : 
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/cp/utilities/cache.html

For EE2:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/cp/tools/data/clear_cached_data_files.html

Comment: Clearing cache does not correct the numberous php errros that I am receiving